# That was a mistake what made him famous/ what have made him famous..wich one i should use?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

We have to write an interview from english and I'm not sure wich one should I use?..or if it's there even a differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

In the English of several centuries ago, and surviving in some dialects, the word **what** can introduce a relative clause as **that** can, but in modern standard English we don't use **what**:

> That's a baseball cap **what** he has on his head. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> That's a baseball cap **that** he has on his head. <sup>YES</sup>

Also, the third person singular of **have** is **has**.

The difference between **made** and **has made** is that with the simple past, his fame was something that arose in the past—he could even be dead now and long forgotten— whereas with **has made**, the present perfect, his fame is something that exists today.

> That was a mistake that *has* made him famous.

Comment: The form is very much alive in London, but it is not standard, as you say.